# microbatch operation in foreachRDD block of spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How can we microbatch operations in foreachRDD block . For example , I read logs from HDFS and perform operation in foreachRDD

```
val lines = ssc.textFileStream(hadoopPath)
lines.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
   val newRDD = rdd.map(line =>
   ScalaObject.process(line)  
}
```

The code will call `ScalaObject.process` for each line in logs. Is is possbile to call `ScalaObject.process` for a batch of lines ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "a batch of lines"? Do you want to process the whole file at once?

Comment: Not whole file , but collection of lines or if possible all the lines in that RDD at once .

Comment: Actually the mapping function applies the ScalaObject.process in a parallel matter. So I don't understand what is the actually issue here.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your example, what you're asking to do will not make use of Spark's parallelism. If you really need to do this for some reason, you can run the processing only once per partition. The parallelism you get with this will only be N, where N is the number of partitions.

Use `rdd.foreachPartition`:

```scala
val lines = ssc.textFileStream(hadoopPath)
  lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val newRDD = rdd.foreachPartition(lines =>
    ScalaObject.process(lines)
  )
}
```

The parameter `lines` will be of type `Iterable[String]`.